# AngularJS: trouble deleting item within ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs-ng-repeat

It seems I can not find this bug. If I delete first item in list, the last one gets deleted. Can anyone see what am I doing wrong?

**HTML**

```
<div ng-repeat="additional in clientAdditionals track by $index">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <ng-form name="additionalSelectFieldForm">
                <select class="form-control" ng-options="item.label for item in clientAdditionalsSelectItems" name="additionalSelect" ng-model="item" ng-change="setClientAdditionals($index, item.name); validateClientAdditionals();" ng-required="true"></select>
            </ng-form>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group col-xs-6">
            <div class="input-button-on-right">
                <div class="withInput">
                    <ng-form name="additionalValueFieldForm">
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="additionalValue" ng-model="additional.value" ng-required="true" />
                    </ng-form>
                </div>
                <div class="withButton">
                    <button class="btn btn-primary circle" ng-click="deleteClientAdditionals(additional)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

**AngularJS**

```
$scope.clientAdditionals = [];

$scope.createClientAdditional = function(item) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals.push({
        name   : undefined,
        value  : undefined 
    });
};

$scope.setClientAdditionals = function(index, name) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals[index].name = name;        
}

$scope.deleteClientAdditionals = function(additional) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals.splice($scope.clientAdditionals.indexOf(additional), 1);
    $scope.validateClientAdditionals();
};
```

If you need some more of the code or some extra explanation, please let me know.

Comment: If you put a console.log(additional) inside your deleteClientAdditionals function, what is the output?

Comment: Object {name: "taxNo" , value: undefuned}

Comment: Ah, so it's an unnamed object. Which is probably why indexOf() doesn't work. I'll answer with an alternative solution

Comment: I have tried with $index. I can try again :)

Answer (score 1):

You could iterate through clientAdditionals with a for-loop, like:

```
for(var i=0; i < $scope.clientAdditionals.length; i++) {
    if($scope.clientAdditionals[i].name == additionals.name && $scope.clientAdditionals[i].value == additionals.value) {
        $scope.clientAdditionals.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update**

You could add an ID property to the array elements. so:

```
$scope.clientAdditionals = [];
$scope.id = 0;

$scope.createClientAdditional = function(item) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals.push({
        id     : undefined,
        name   : undefined,
        value  : undefined 
    });
};

$scope.setClientAdditionals = function(index, name) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals[index].id = $scope.id;
    $scope.clientAdditionals[index].name = name;   
    $scope.id++;     
}
```

Then the for loop could be adjusted to be:

```
for(var i=0; i < $scope.clientAdditionals.length; i++) {
    if($scope.clientAdditionals[i].id == additionals.id) {
        $scope.clientAdditionals.splice(i, 1);
        break;
    }
}
```

**Update2**

Or, if you are 100% sure that the ID property is equal to the position of the array element, so if `$scope.clientAdditionals[i].id == i`, you could omit the for-loop and do this:

html:

```
<div class="withButton">
    <button class="btn btn-primary circle" ng-click="deleteClientAdditionals(additional.id)"><span class="fa fa-times"></span></button>
</div>
```

controller:

```
$scope.deleteClientAdditionals = function(index) {
    $scope.clientAdditionals.splice(index, 1);
    $scope.validateClientAdditionals();
};
```

Comment: I have tried with this solution and it fails with same issue. I did a test if code gets into for and into if statement - it does but still deletes the wrong one.

Comment: Are there more entries in the array with the same name/value? because it will delete the first hit, maybe that's where it goes wrong?

Comment: There is some same pairs in array, true. How could I solve this issue then?

Comment: Updated my answer. Something in this direction I guess?

Comment: Guinn, thank you for trying. I will try this solution although I wonder why is this not working with simple solution with delete($index) and then splice($index, 1).

Comment: I don't know why since I don't have your entire code, so I can't test it. You could try to console.log the $index and see what the result is and whether that matches the position of the array element you want to delete.

Comment: I have tried it out. Console.log outputs the right index, so this is even stranger. Perhaps there is an issue with my selects - I will try to provide code.

Comment: This is true, there is something wrong with my selects. Somehow values get updated on delete and this caused fake error, although item was deleted just fine. I will try to debug on my own, thank you again.

Comment: Guinn do you some some strange code which causes the following scenario? I have replaced select field with input field, now I have two in a row. I created 3 rows and put values in inputs (0,0; 1,1; 2,2). When I delete first row, results is 0,1; 1,2 instead of 1,1; 2,2. Sorry, I wasn't able to put code in online editor.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, this has been resolved.

The bug was causing data in `ng-model="item"`. I have changed it into `ng-model="additional.selected"` and deleting item now works.